# Issue converting JSON string into decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, casting, decimal

This question may answer on many threads but I am unable to find answer specific to my problem.

Q: I am getting data from API (in json format) where all columns are coming as string and inserting into a table which has all columns as string and serving as source table.

Now, I am trying to cast data from that source to destination and making all necessary casting to insert data into destination table. But decimal (16,8) casting failed.

I debug issue at my end and found that during the fetching data from API which is returning the data into json format converting values in some unusual format.

For e.g. 0.00007 converting into 7E-05 and this is happening for many other rows.

I know I can fix this problem at API implementation level. But I asked to solve this at SQL server end. So I need a solution which should convert 7E-05 into 0.00007.

Comment: Fixing this at the source is the right way to handle this. It would require some ugly string manipulation to do this in sql.

Comment: Hmm. Is that form consistent? What will it diplay for 5? for 15? for 1.345?

Comment: Also note that converting from JSON to float/decimal will convert back into a string format when you insert again into your stated column. Will this value always be a string-type or will it always be a decimal-type? There is a lot of behind-the-scenes conversion happening. It would be best to set your destination table datatype to whatever datatype it's actually expected to hold. If the values are decimals, make it a decimal column.

Comment: Hi All,
Thanks for the quick responses. SQL part is solved my problem so far.
Let me tell you the reason behind the extracting everything as string from string.
As part of solution, API implementation is something where we don't want to fail our crone jobs to fetch the data because we can't control the data from our vendor and our vendor frequently change the system due to change in market dynamics. So it would be easy for us to implement most of the thing at sql level where we would debug easily and if needed can deploy any change in production with least down time and easy to handle.

Comment: @RahulNeekhra This is a very common use case. Most recommended is a tolerant staging table. This is the target of your import. From this staging table you can do any kind of validation / conversion and shift the data into the real targets. Btw: It is kind to say "Thanks", but even kinder to vote and accept if this is solved ;-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *unusual format* is a rather usual *scientific notation* [Wikipedia, read section "E-notation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)

You see the `E` and a number meaning *exponent*.

```
"1E2"  = 1 * 10^2 = 100
"1E-2" = 1 * 10^(-2) = 0.01
```

Try this out:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Numberstring VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('100'),('1E2'),('1E-2'),('7E-05');
SELECT Numberstring
      ,CAST(Numberstring AS FLOAT) 
      ,CAST(CAST(Numberstring AS FLOAT) AS DECIMAL(20,10)) 
FROM @tbl;
```

The result

```
100     100     100.0000000000
1E2     100     100.0000000000
1E-2    0,01    0.0100000000
7E-05   7E-05   0.0000700000
```

You can see, that the `FLOAT` type itself will display the last one in the scientific notation, while the cast to `DECIMAL` will return the number you are expecting.

I'd be happy with an upvote, but you should accept Shawn's answer as it was earlier than mine :-D

Answer (score 6):

Try something like:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(@t AS FLOAT) AS DECIMAL(16,8))
```

Results in:

```
0.00007000
```

`CAST` to a `FLOAT`, then to a `DECIMAL`.

Comment: Good point. Probably be better to trim the variable in case the JSON pads or includes empty characters.

Comment: Any spaces would just get dropped when converting to a numeric datatype. The trim is just not needed. Maybe need a try_cast but otherwise this should be ok.

Comment: And I would recommend the `TRY_CAST`, but that is a SQL 2012+ function. A custom scalar function that does the same thing might be good if 2008R2 or less.

Comment: @Shawn, there is a really nice trick for versions below 2012 using XML's cast: `SELECT CAST('32' AS XML).value('. cast as xs:int?','int')` This can be done fully inline... Try to replace `32` with a bad value and you simply get `NULL`.